# How to draw a line perpendicular to another line (3D object) in 3D space according to it's local axis in three.js?

Tags: graphics, three.js, coordinates

I am new to webgl graphics, I am looking for a way in three.js to draw a line which is perpendicular to another line(already exisiting line in 3D space) with respect to line's local axis (draw line to first line's z- local axis for example).
[image: draw line to another line's local axis]

Comment: In general, the way you do that is with **cross-product**.  There's really a lot to know about 3D math if you're wanting to do 3D stuff (regardless of platform).

Comment: In this case I think I will need another line in order to perform cross product, the problem here that I only one line in space to begin with.
maybe defining a new vector in global direction and cross product with the existing line's vector can yeild the desired result?

Comment: Sure.  this page https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/UnderstandingVectorArithmetic.html  scroill down to "Cross Product" heading and diagram will explain it, as does my answer below

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked nicely, thak you.
multiplied (cross-product) vector of line's direction X unit vector of up direction, getting a vector perpendicular, normalized this vector then re-multiplied it with the line vector to get the two other vectors representing the local axis of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the line has a "local axis"

Note that **the local X or Y axis of the line** is indeed exactly what you are asking for.

The local **X or Y axis** of a line is indeed a line perpendicular to the line.

The local z axis of a line is simply the line itself.  Local X and Y are perpendicular.

---

Are you aware that, for a given line L, you are asking for a "perpendicular line".  **There is an infinite number of lines perpendicular to L**, in fact what you are describing is a plane (perhaps think of it as a disk); L goes through the "middle of" the disk at right angles.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, the local up direction is the y-direction is the up direction and the z axis is an axis that is through the line.
In order to get the perpendicular axis I used two lines, I had to cross-product a vector in Y-global (0,1,0) and the line's direction vector, getting  a vector perpendicular to that plan

Comment: cheers @WaleedHany , be sure to tick or vote any answers (it gives you "rights" to ask more questions you know), see you on the next question !